# Buiding javascript with Makefile

Tags: javascript, node.js, makefile

I have cloned a nodejs project, and the project containes a Makefile

```
SRC = $(wildcard lib/**/*.js)
CSS = $(wildcard lib/**/*.css)
HTML = $(wildcard lib/**/*.html)
COMPONENTJSON = $(wildcard lib/*/component.json)
TEMPLATES = $(HTML:.html=.js)

build: components $(SRC) $(CSS) $(TEMPLATES)
    @echo building
    @component build

components: component.json $(COMPONENTJSON)
    @echo installing
    @component install

%.js: %.html
    @echo converting
    @component convert $<

minify:
    @component build --use component-minify

clean:
    @echo cleaning
    rm -fr build components $(TEMPLATES)

.PHONY: clean minify
```

I didnot know before that make can be used to build javascript, and when i am running `make` I am getting the error

```
installing
make: component: Command not found
make: *** [components] Error 127
```

My qestion is,

**1.is it using the same default make provided by unix system, or is it using some kind of other node library?


2.if it is the same system default, why I am getting the error?**

[link to the example project](https://github.com/souparno/abecedary/tree/master/example)

Comment: Did you get any solution? Please share. Thanks.

Comment: @Waqas yes, the reason i was receiving the error was because components was not installed in my sytsem, its the same makefile as in the unix system, that is using the installed node component to run the taks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is using the same `make` found in any unix/linux system.
The error was due to the unavailability of the `component` package. I installed `component` using:

```
npm install -g component
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a life saviour :)

Comment: @Waqas, no problem. are you working on the abecedary project?

Comment: No sir, it was required in another Ecommerce related project.